# Print only numbers from table from database in mysql

Tags: python, mysql

Sorry this question is so badly worded. Basically, I have a highscore column in my database, and I want to query the database for these values in descending order. This is how I so this:

```
highscore_list = ("SELECT highscore FROM users ORDER BY highscore DESC")
cursor.execute(highscore_list)
results = cursor.fetchall()
for i in results:
    print(i)
```

The values I have in the highscore column are 0, 0, 1000.
When I run this code I get an output of `(1000,)  (0,)  (0,)` Is there way to remove the brackets and comma so I am instead left with `1000` `0` `0`. I am using python and mysql.

Comment: This does not work :/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can see here to find out why that is caused and how it can be fixed within your code - [mysql remove brackets from printed data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23040236/sqlite3-remove-brackets-from-printed-data)

You can also, since `cursor.fetchall()` returns an iterable list, you can simply modify the values in a `pythonic` manner.

For example,

```
lst = [(1000,) , (0,) , (0,)]
correct = [str(x)[1:-2] for x in lst ]
results = list(map(int, correct))
print(results)
```

outputs:

```
root@00973a947f4e:/root# python app.py
[1000, 0, 0]
```